Thermochemistry: Combustion of Nitrous Oxide and Isopropyanol
I have the following reaction:
$$\ce{C3H7OH + 9N2O -> 3CO2 + 4H2O + 9N2}$$
I calculated the heat of a combustion reaction for this to be the following:
$$\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ = \pu{-2610.26 kJ mol-1}$$
Is this correct?

Isn't last product $\ce{N2}$?

Im not sure, this is a combustion reaction, so the Nitrous oxide goes into decomposition, but Im not sure if the nitrogen atoms would split as well.

What do you mean by "saturated liquid state"? There is a value for the aqueous dissolved state (usual 1 mol/kg standard state).

It's liquid, if aqueous means the same thing. What is the value? thanks in advance

@Joshua Humphreys: I don't necessarily agree with aqueous and liquid states are same. Also, according to your above statement, $\ce{N}$ in your equation should be $\ce{N^.}$.

I just fixed it, it's N2

What is N∙? like you mentioned

FYI: $\ce{N^.}$ is a radical $\ce{N}$.

The NBS tables [1] lists $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ = \pu{+56.1 kJ mol^{-1}}$. This is for $\ce{N2O}$ dissolved in water at an unspecified state of dilution (basically very dilute).
1: D.D. Wagman et al, The NBS tables of chemical thermodynamic properties, J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data, Vol 11, 1982, Supplement 2.

So I was just working with someone else, and we subtracted enthalpy of vaporization of N2O from gas state N2O. ΔfH∘=+82 kJ/mol - 16.53 KJ/mol. I guess its similar. There

feel free to correct me :)

I corrected my post with the correct equation and our enthalpy of formation calculation

So the value derived from the enthalpy of vaporization is for pure liquid N2O, which is quite different, but may be what you want.

We will be using pure N2O for our propellant, so my calc was correct? Should be 65.47 KJ/mol?

That's the right calculation for pure liquid N2O

From your post, I assumed that you have been researching a new combustion system using nitrous oxide $(\ce{N2O})$ as an oxidant with isopropanol as fuel. Although it is not a flammable gas (but known for centuries as laughing gas), $\ce{N2O}$ has been identified as an important intermediate during the combustion of many propellants in all states (solid, liquid, and gaseous) because its ability to provide additional oxygen for the combustion by readily undergoing thermal degradation exothermally, producing nitrogen and oxygen (Ref. 1):
$$\ce{N2O -> N2 + 1/2 O2} \quad (\Delta_\mathrm{f} H^\circ = \pu{-82 kJ mol-1}) \tag1 $$
It’s important to note that at ambient temperature, the decomposition of $\ce{N2O}$ is slow. It has been shown that at the same working pressure and temperature, the $\ce{N2O}$ decomposition rate is 6 orders of magnitude slower than that of hydrogen peroxide $(\ce{H2O,})$, making it a much safer propellant. Since $\ce{N2O}$  is not a flammable gas, there have been several suggested ways to ignite the propellent mixtures, which are not using oxygen $(\ce{O2})$, for instance, see following illustration of a model for these types of combustion systems without using $\ce{O2}$ (Ref. 1):

There have been plethora of studied done in presence of various conditions including with and without $\ce{O2}$ atmosphere.  To properly describe the chemistry of hydrocarbon oxidation with $\ce{N2O}$ to accurately model the gas phase kinetics of all types of propellant combustions, several studies have been performed (For review see Ref. 1). For instance, a recent study using ignition delay-times for system containing small hydrocarbons (e.g., $\ce{CH4, C2H6, H2C=CH2, HC#CH}$)–$\ce{N2O}$ mixtures with and without $\ce{O2}$ were investigated through shock-tube experiments and chemical kinetic simulations (Ref. 2). As concluded by these authors, experimentally they have shown that the addition of oxygen induces a significant reduction of the activation energy of the ignition process (25% lower on average).  of the ignition process. Yet, simulations demonstrate that delay-times are delay-times are usually satisfactorily predicted but that the detailed reaction models used do not capture all the features of the excited OH radicals, $\ce{OH^*}$, emission profiles, so that it is required to include a sub-mechanism for their chemistry when modeling (Ref. 2). This probably means the usual combustion reactions of these types are incomplete most of the time (keep in mind that $\ce{OH^*}$ is typically 6 orders of magnitude lower than that of $\ce{OH^.}$).
My point for giving these information here is your calculations should be included for energy release/absorbed by all these side reactions to calculate intended target: the heat of the given combustion reaction (Hess' law). Note that the equation given in the problem is for the fully completed combustion in simplified form (it is true that the system is producing nitrogen gas as a byproduct alongside the typical combustion products like carbon dioxide and water vapor) without concerning formation of some other species such as two mentioned above (see some suggested mechanisms given in Ref. 3 (click on the link to download the PDF), for example. Keep also in mind that those species can also escaped the system by emission. Also, combustion system with use of isopropanol has been already known as well (Ref. 4). Yet, your system may have novelty based on the use different ignition mechanism, etc.
For your information, the following data might be useful in your calculations:

Enthalpy of vaporization of $\ce{N2O}$ is given as $\pu{16.5 kJ mol-1}$ in Ref. 5 at $\pu{184.7 K}$ (the boiling point of $\ce{N2O}$).
Latent heat of vaporization of $\ce{N2O}$ is given as $\pu{16.55 kJ mol-1}$ in Ref. 6 at $\pu{184.695 K}$ (the boiling point of $\ce{N2O}$) and given as $\pu{16.66 kJ mol-1}$ at $\pu{182.351 K}$ (the triple point of $\ce{N2O}$).
Enthalpy of formation of gaseous $\ce{N2O}$ $(\Delta_\mathrm{f} H^\circ)$ is given as $\pu{85.5 J mol-1}$ at $\pu{0 K}$ and $\pu{82.05 kJ mol-1}$ at $\pu{298.15 K}$ (pressure: $\pu{1 bar}$) in Ref. 7 (p. 2-64).
Heat capacity of gaseous $\ce{N2O}$ at constant pressure $(C_p)$ is given as $\pu{38.45 J mol-1 K-1}$ at $\pu{298.15 K}$ (pressure: $\pu{1 bar}$) in Ref. 7 (p. 2-64).


References:

Domnina Razus, “Nitrous Oxide: Oxidizer and Promoter of Hydrogen and Hydrocarbon Combustion,” Ind. Eng. Chem. Res. 2022, 61(31), 11329–11346 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.iecr.2c01774).
R. Mével and J. E. Shepherd, “Ignition delay-time behind reflected shock waves of small hydrocarbons–nitrous oxide(–oxygen) mixtures,” Shock Waves 2015, 25, 217–229 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/s00193-014-0509-4).
John C. Kramlich and William P. Linak, “Nitrous Oxide Behavior in the Atmosphere, and in Combustion and Industrial Systems,” Progress in Energy and Combustion Science 1994, 20(2),149-202 (The link for PDF).
G. Capriolo, N. Bystrov, A. Emelianov, A. Eremin, P. Yatsenko, and A. A. Konnov, “High-temperature oxidation of propanol isomers in the mixtures with $\ce{N2O}$ at high Ar dilution conditions,” Fuel 2021, 287, Article 119499 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fuel.2020.119499).
Tooru Atake and Hideaki Chihara, "A New Condensed Gas Calorimeter. Thermodynamic Properties of Solid and Liquid Dinitrogen Oxide," Bulletin of the Chemical Society of Japan 1974, 47(9), 2126–2136 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1246/bcsj.47.2126).
Harald J. Hoge, “Vapor pressure, latent heat of vaporization, and triple-point temperature of $\ce{N2O}$,” Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards 1945, 34(3), 281-293 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.6028/jres.034.015).
Donald D. Wagman, William H. Evans, Vivian B. Parker, Richard H. Schumm, Iva Halow, Sylvia M. Bailey, Kenneth L. Churney, and Ralph L. Nuttall, “The NBS Tables of Chemical Thermodynamic Properties: Selected Values for Inorganic and $\ce{C1}$ and $\ce{C2}$ Organic Substances in SI Units,” Journal of Physical and Chemical Reference Data 1982, 11, Supplement No. 2 (pp. 2-1 – 2-392) (Available at https://srd.nist.gov/JPCRD/jpcrdS2Vol11.pdf).


So the system I am using is a bi-propellant liquid rocket. In the propellant tank, there is oxidizer on the bottom and a hydrocarbon fuel on top.

The nitrous oxide on the bottom will go into decomposition due to the change in volume (Charle's law) boiling off into a vapor which will push the piston upwards squeezing out the fuel into the fluid valve system into the thrust chamber where it will combust with a cartridge igniter.

Could H2O be used as an oxidizer? with the added flavor of a lot more heat produced.

Also, does decomposition of nitrous oxide already happening in the propellant tank mean it doesn't decompose a second time in the combustion chamber, but rather excited with the OH?

Sorry for all the questions, just sincerely trying to understand.

"provides a reference for propulsion
characteristics as a function of temperature, which
dictates N2O pressure and density. The given
ambient temperatures are of the outside air, and not
the temperature of oxidizer in the propellant tank.
During the oxidizer fill, the liquid typically cools
down to approximately 12° F colder than it was in the
supply bottle, so that it reaches a correspondingly
lower equilibrium pressure (12° F was determined
empirically during Mojave Sphinx testing, and can
vary depending on vent orifice and tank sizing).

Additionally, temperatures listed are for bottles in
shade – direct sunlight will raise the temperature
and pressure further, sometimes significantly
higher than air temperature. On hot days, bottles
should be shielded from sunlight and/or cooled with
ice or a wet towel; the latter was found to decrease
bottle pressure by as much as 10 psi per minute
when the towel was kept continuously soaked. On
very cold days, sunlight can be used to keep
pressure up. Regardless of the temperature, if a
pressure gauge is present on the supply bottle or
GSE,

this should be used as a more accurate reading
of oxidizer condition.
All values in Table 2.6 are for alcohol fuels (E85,
isopropanol, etc.) using the BASIC-6-6 injector. If a
hydrocarbon like diesel is used instead, multiply
chamber pressure, thrust, total impulse, and
altitude by 0.8 for a more accurate performance
estimate"

I think you should read all seven references I have noted. Sometimes, more reading will get you confused, but I recommend  careful reading with understanding. I learned a lot by just reading these papers.
